# How do I perform WhenAll on an array of TaskAwaiters?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am using an API that returns awaitable objects that aren't tasks (in fact, they are `PendingResult` instances from Google's Android API). I would like to await completion of all of them. But I can only await an array of tasks under the current model.

The CTP of the TPL had a `TaskEx.WhenAll()` extension, which you could use to await `TaskAwaiter` instances. But `Task.WhenAll()` only applies to `Task` instances.

How can I perform `WhenAll` on an array of `TaskAwaiter` instances?

Comment: The [docs on TaskAwaiter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter(v=vs.110).aspx) say _"This type and its members are intended for compiler use only."_

Comment: You're not meant to be using this struct directly anymore - why can't you use the Task instead?

Comment: Why are  you using the CTP?  That's been obsolete for like 5 years now.

Comment: I'm not using the CTP. I didn't say I was using it. However, I am using an interface that returns an awaitable result that isn't a `Task`. An awaitable result has a `GetTaskAwaiter()` method.

Comment: _"How can I perform WhenAll on an array of TaskAwaiter instances?"_ -- please clarify. Do you actually have `TaskAwaiter` instances returned from the API? Or do you have actual _awaitable_ objects returned from the API? I.e. a type for which `GetAwaiter()` is defined? If the latter, the solution is easy (see the answer posted below). If the former, it's not much harder...you just have to wrap the `TaskAwaiter` in an object that will return the value via a `GetAwaiter()` method and then apply the answer posted below. But your question is too vague and unclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The CTP of the TPL had a TaskEx.WhenAll() extension, which you could use to await TaskAwaiter instances.

Are you sure? I don't remember that. Then again, it was a long time ago, so I may just not remember.

> I am using an interface that returns an awaitable result that isn't a Task. An awaitable result [that] has a GetTaskAwaiter() method.

If it's returning a custom awaitable, then you can just use `async`/`await` to convert that to a `Task`:

```
async Task DoSomethingAsync(string parameter) => await NonTaskAsync(parameter);
```

And use `Select` as such:

```
string[] parameters = ...;
var tasks = parameters.Select(DoSomethingAsync);
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```